# TypeError: object Response can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio

I am trying to execute this unit test. I would like to asynchronously await the GET as it takes a while to retrieve data. However, I am getting: `TypeError: object Response can't be used in 'await' expression`.

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_report(report_service, client, headers):
    """Test Report GET Response"""
    report_id = "sample-report-id"

    report_service.query_db.query_fetchone = mock.AsyncMock(
        return_value={
            "id": "sample-id",
            "reportId": "sample-report-id",
            "reportName": "sample-report-name",
            "report": [],
        }
    )
    response = await client.get(f"/v2/report/{report_id }", headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

If I remove the `await`, I will get this response `{'detail': 'Not Found'}`.

Answer (score 1):

**client.get** is not an asynchronous function, that is why you are getting the error. I guess you are using FastAPI, that '.get' function is synchronous. In your case i guess the following might work:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_report(report_service, client, headers):
"""Test Report GET Response"""
report_id = "sample-report-id"

report_service.query_db.query_fetchone = mock.AsyncMock(
    return_value={
        "id": "sample-id",
        "reportId": "sample-report-id",
        "reportName": "sample-report-name",
        "report": [],
    }
)
async with client.get(f"/v2/report/{report_id}", headers=headers) as response:
    assert response.status == 200
```

Hope this works.

Comment: I got this error > ```async with client.get(f"/v2/internal-resource/{internal_resource_id}", headers=headers) as response:
E       AttributeError: __aenter__```